# How concatenate columns in excel repeatedly

Tags: vba, excel, concatenation

I have 256 columns in a excel sheet. I need to bring them to 128 columns by merging pairs of columns. How can I repeat the process of concatenating two cells throughout the sheet

Eg:

```
Col | Col2  | Col3 | Col4

1:  | 45    |  2:  |  556

1:  | 34    |  2:  |  567
```

Now my expected result is

```
Col1 | Col2

1:45 | 2:556

1:34 | 2:567
```

How can I perform this in Excel?

Can I use VBA?

Comment: Use `For Col = 1 to 256 Step 2` loop, and then inisde do your `Concatenate`

Comment: Should I use VB or can I do it in excel

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the formula (in cell `A4` in image below)

```
=OFFSET(A1, , COLUMN()-1)&OFFSET(B1,,COLUMN()-1)
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Thanks @Tom this formula works well for small dataset. My data contains 256 rows & colums so could not apply this.

Answer (score 2):

Add two columns with the simple formula =A2&B2. Copy down. then copy resulting formula columns and paste special values to get rid of formula.

Comment: The problem is that you have 256 columns with data in. To use a formula you will either have to put your formula into columns 257 to 385 or repeatedly insert a column, drag down, turn to values, delete columns A and B etc. So a macro is fastest solution

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that range is "A1:IV1000" (change to what you need). In the end the original range is cleared and resulting array is dumped.

```
Sub ConcatColumns()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim x As Long, c As Integer, z As Integer
    Dim arr, arrResult
    Const COLS As Integer = 256

    Set rng = Range("A1:IV100") '//256 columns
    arr = rng.Value
    ReDim arrResult(1 To UBound(arr, 1), 1 To COLS / 2)
    For x = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        z = 1
        For c = 1 To COLS - 1 Step 2
            arrResult(x, z) = arr(x, c) & arr(x, c + 1)
            z = z + 1
        Next
    Next

    rng.ClearContents '//Clear all previous data
    Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrResult, 1), UBound(arrResult, 2)).Value = arrResult '//Dump result

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much @JohnyL this VBA worked fantastic. My entire data was  processed in a jiffy.